# Run function on all module components run

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this configuration:

`- channel.module.ts
 - channel.component.ts
 - channel.component.html
 - ...
 - component1
    - component1.component.ts
 - component2
    - component2.component.ts`

All subcomponents inherits views from channel.component.html.
So, i would like to check if user has some privileges when he want to access to all channel module sub-components and redirect him to specific page.

I got the idea to implement the verification in the ngOnInit of the channel.component.ts but it's only running the first time.

Do you have any idea about this achievement?

Regards

Comment: Maybe using Guards on routes directing required components

Comment: @AshishRanjan thank you, it works !